# Why does xDebug do not work with Php Storm on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm, ubuntu-14.04, xdebug

I have installed xdebug and tried to use it with phpstorm. But it doesn't want work correctly.

I tried to put following settings to `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/mods-avaible/xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"

; Debugging
xdebug.remote_enable= 1
xdebug.remote_port= 9000
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"

; Var-Display
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 8192
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 99
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 3000
```

I thought the `xdebug.ini should be the correct place for this settings.

Then I restarted apache with `sudo service apache2 restart` and opened a page where I print out `phpinfo()`. But as you can see on screenshot - it says all the time `netbeans-xdebug`.

[image]

What can I do? I searched my whole system for other php.ini files, but there aren't any other files.

Comment: Well apparently somewhere in the past you did something with netbeans xdebug. http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug . Did you check those ini files mentioned in the 'additional ini files parsed' section?

Comment: I even do not have netbeans installed. But I think that must be a default value. I've already posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** to my problem.

I figured out that in my browser, even after restarting my system (obviously) a cookie `XDEBUG_SESSION=netbeans-xdebug` was causing this problem.

After deleting it and reloading my `phpinfo()` page, my new `idekey` is `PHPSTORM` and now xdebug works with my ide.

I think the problem was that I installed xdebug and tried it with my ide without setting it up - so (default?) value for `idekey` was this `netbeans-xdebug` value. And as soon as the cookie is set, it will ignore php settings as long as this cookie is alive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me.

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
```

But run following command first to locate `xdebug.so`

```
locate xdebug.so
```

and change following line accordingly

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens (if the path to xdebug.so is correct) because the remote_enable is set to off.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
```

might solve the issue.